# Android Retrofit RestAdapter get failed status on disconnection

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, retrofit

In my app I am uploading images to AWS via Retrofit with this code:

```
private interface UploadFileToAwsInterface {
        @Multipart
        @POST("/")
        SuccessResponse uploadFile(@Part("key") String key,
                                   @Part("AWSAccessKeyId") String AWSAccessKeyId,
                                   @Part("acl") String acl,
                                   @Part("success_action_redirect") String success_action_redirect,
                                   @Part("policy") String policy,
                                   @Part("signature") String signature,
                                   @Part("utf8") String utf8,
                                   @Part("Content-Type") String contType,
                                   @Part("file") TypedFile file);
    }

    public Boolean uploadFileToAws(AWSCredentials awsCredentials, File localFile, String mimeType) {
        TypedFile file = new TypedFile(mimeType, localFile);
        endPoint.setUrl(awsCredentials.getAction());
        UploadFileToAwsInterface uploadFileInterface = restAdapter.create(UploadFileToAwsInterface.class);
        SuccessResponse response = uploadFileInterface.uploadFile(
                awsCredentials.getKey(),
                awsCredentials.getAWSAccessKeyId(),
                awsCredentials.getAcl(),
                awsCredentials.getSuccess_action_redirect(),
                awsCredentials.getPolicy(),
                awsCredentials.getSignature(),
                "true",
                mimeType,
                file);
```

Image uploading works fine. But when I start image upload and network disconnect, I can't get response. How I can get failure in such situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch [RetrofitError](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/RetrofitError.html) when you call uploadFileInterface.uploadFile():

```
try {
  SuccessResponse response = uploadFileInterface.uploadFile(
      awsCredentials.getKey(),
      awsCredentials.getAWSAccessKeyId(),
      awsCredentials.getAcl(),
      awsCredentials.getSuccess_action_redirect(),
      awsCredentials.getPolicy(),
      awsCredentials.getSignature(), 
      "true", 
      mimeType, 
      file);
} catch (RetrofitError error) {
  //TODO Show exception here
}
```